# How to make JUnit4 lifecycle callbacks work in ScalaTest with JUnitRunner?

Tags: scala, scalatest

According to ScalaTest documentation [it's possible to use JUnitRunner](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_junit_runner) to run tests. My assumption was, if it runs with JUnitRunner, its callback methods (i.e. methods marked with `@Before` or `@After` annotation should work as well. But apparently my assumption was wrong. I've created simple example to demonstrate it:

```
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.{FunSuite, _}
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class Test extends FunSuite {

  @Before
  def before() = {
    println("before test")
  }

  test("nothing") {
    println("test is started")
  }
}
```

If you run this example, you'll see `test is started` line, but not `before test`.

I'm aware of ScalaTest lifecycle callbacks, but the thing is I need to make JUnit callbacks work somehow. I want to write a test for Play 2.4 application and the thing it's `play.test.WithBrowser` class relies on JUnit callbacks. I  found this workaround for the issue:

```
 var testBrowser : TestBrowser = _

 before {
   new WithBrowser {
     override def createBrowser(): Unit = {
       super.createBrowser()
       testBrowser = browser
     }
 }.createBrowser()
```

}

but I believe it's quite ugly and I suspect that there is a better way.

So, my question is if it's possible to make these JUnit lifecycle callbacks work with ScalaTest? And if it is possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `JUnitSuite` instead of `FunSuite`. The documentation is here:

http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_junit_4_in_scala
http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/index.html#org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuite

Answer (score 0):

I did just like Noah suggested and it worked. Just in case anyone stumbles upon the same issue with Play 2.x and `WithBrowser`, I ended up with a test like this:

```
class IntegrationSpec extends WithBrowser with JUnitSuiteLike with Matchers {

  @Test def workWithBrowser() {
     browser.goTo("http://localhost:9000")
     browser.pageSource should include("Add Person")
  }
}
```